# CucumberJs - Protractor - TypeScript - Dynamic Tags/Variables on .feature file

Tags: typescript, protractor, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, cucumberjs

I'm trying to resolve the problem in which I have different environments, and in all of them, or most, I have different features enabled.
What I am trying to achieve, is to automate as much as possible in the CI/CD environment with the variables that it has, so I would like to read those variables and run the tests as they are set up, so, I would like to have only one job that I can reuse and read/use from, put them in the protractor config file, or somehow add them to the features files. Is that possible? Is there anyway I could set `@tags` in the feature file? so I do not have to create different jobs for the different combination of features/environments?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, create 2 json files with a set of variables.

Then in your config file create an if/else block where you assign either one to browser.params depending on a parameter that you pass to protractor

Start protractor passing the name of environment under test as an argument

Let me know if you need a full answer